# Loop through a complex object of array in vue to get a particular field populated in dropdown

Tags: vue.js, dropdown, v-for

This is my object i want to loop through

```
{
"_msgid":"22343sadda",
"payload":
   {
   "@status":"green",
   "@code":"19",
   "result":
        {
        "@total-count":"2",
         "@count":"2",
          "entry": 
             [{
              "@id":"abc123",
              "@location":"vcfa"
              },
              {
             "@id":"ftef",
               "@location":"562532"
                }]
        }
    }
}
```

This is my frontend where i just want @id to be populated in dropdown

```
<bc-dropdown label="Dropdown object"  v-model="form.location" @select="getGroups">
<bc-dropdown-option v-for="g in groupOptions"  :key="g._msgid" :value="g">
  </bc-dropdown-option>
  </bc-dropdown>
```

This is the method which gives me the object in return

```
getGroups() {
            axios.get("api/getGroups").then((response) => {
                this.groupOptions= response.data;
                console.log("groups", this.groupOptions);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
            });
```

Currently i am getting entire object in dropdown. Kindly help me with the proper code to just populate @id from return object

Updated:

[image] I want populate @name in the dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dropdown options array is `response.data.payload.result.entry` not `response.data`.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <select v-model="selectedEntry">
                <option v-for="entry in payload.result.entry" :value="entry['@id']">{{entry['@location']}}</option>
            </select>
            <h4>Selected Entry: {{selectedEntry}}</div>
        </div>
    `,
    data: {
        payload: {
            result: {
            entry: [{
              "@id":"abc123",
              "@location":"vcfa"
            }, {
                "@id":"ftef",
              "@location":"562532"
            }]
          }
        },
        selectedEntry: ""
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: When i use **response.data.payload.result.entry** it show me error in my front end **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'result')**

Comment: But as per the json you posted. result object is inside payload. Looks like the JSON you posted in the question is not correct. Please update the correct one.

Comment: Its the same and i am referencing groupOptions in data as below **data: {
        groupOptions: {}}** should it be **groupOptions: []** ???

Comment: Can you please post your `response.data` in your question ? That will help me in identifying the loop hole.

Comment: Hi @CreativeLearner!!! Could you please help me with the proper code.

Comment: As per the API response you attached .. this is the only way `this.groupOptions.payload.result.entry` you can access your entry.

Comment: Just checking! Did you resolved the issue ?

Comment: Please do upvote & accept this answer if it helps you. So that other developers can take the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `this.groupOptions` to the object you're getting. You need to parse the object and get the array you want to loop through.

```
created() {
   axios.get("api/getGroups").then((response) => {
     this.groupOptions= response.data.payload.result.entry
     console.log("groups", this.groupOptions);
  }).catch(error => {
     ...
  })
}
```

Since `this.groupOptions` is now the array of objects, you can set the value equal to the `@id` field. Since the property name has a special character, you have to use bracket notation to access it.

```
<bc-dropdown label="Dropdown object"  v-model="form.location" @select="setGroup">
  <bc-dropdown-option v-for="g in groupOptions"  :key="g['@id']"  :value="g['@id']" />
</bc-dropdown>
```

Comment: When i use **response.data.payload.result.entry** it show me error in my front end **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'result')**

Comment: Can you do a console.log on the groupOptions after you set it in the api call? That seems like it isn't setting it to the object appropriately. How you have it, assuming data contains the object you are showing, should work. Me and the other guy have basically the same answer